# A ref or out argument must be an assignable variable?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, ref

Error:

> A ref or out argument must be an assignable variable

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class OAKListView : ListView
{
    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);

        this.WndProc(ref new Message()
        {
            HWnd = this.Handle,
            Msg = 4150,
            LParam = (IntPtr)43,
            WParam = IntPtr.Zero
        });
    }
}
```

It shows error

> this.WndProc(ref new Message()

Comment: Yes. If you're passing like this, the method will change nothing!

Comment: how can i resolve this?

Comment: Create a Message() object first, then send it to WndProc.

Comment: @Dolubolu You can assign it to a variable, but this may be wrong. If the method takes a `ref` parameter, it changes it - it says that: if you wrote the method - fix it! if no, check the documenation - maybe you wrong...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error explains it clearly. You need an assignable variable

```
protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnHandleCreated(e);
    var message = new Message()
    {
        HWnd = this.Handle,
        Msg = 4150,
        LParam = (IntPtr)43,
        WParam = IntPtr.Zero
    };
    this.WndProc(ref message);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your ref parameter is not assignable variable. Creating a new new instance of your `Message` class and passing as a reference should not be at the same time. The calling method is supposed to fill in some place in memory. There is no such thing in your call. This would compile:

```
var message = new Message()
{
    HWnd = this.Handle,
    Msg = 4150,
    LParam = (IntPtr)43,
    WParam = IntPtr.Zero
});

this.WndProc(ref message);
```